# How can the lagrange multipliers in a simple constrained cost minimization problem be calculated? (for binding constraints)

Tags: optimization, problem-solving, nonlinear-optimization

Is there a simple algebric way to calculate the shadow prices (lambda) of the binding constraints given below? This is a cost minimization problem dependent on the generation output. The cost of output dependens on the chosen value for x(1), x(2) and the shape of f(x). The objective function, needed parameters,the result of the optimization problem and also the lambdas  are provided below.

```
Min {b(1)* integral(0,x(1),f(x))+c(1)}+{b(2)*integral(x(1),x(1)+x(2),f(x))+c(2)}
where f(x)=1.25*(1-x)
Parameters
c(1)=0
c(2)=0
b(1)=5
b(2)=15
The constraints
x(1)<=0.2 (?lambda 1)
x(2)<=0.8 (?lambda 2)
x(1)+x(2)>=1
0<=x(1)
0<=x(2)
```

The result is x(1)=0.2, x(2)=0.8, lambda(1)=32.3169; lambda(2)=22.3169

Comment: I think your question might attract more attention if you explained some of the economics concepts; perhaps reformulate the question in terms of partial derivatives? Some of us know what a Lagrange multiplier is.

Comment: Shadow price, lagrange multiplier and dual variable are the same things.

Comment: But the second one, used in the title, attracts more mathematicians :-)

Comment: Well, actually this is a simple question for a mathematician :)))

Comment: It's good to know that. Now change the title to catch one :-)

Comment: Not catching one, but lets call it take attention.